# phpmyadmin quota limit error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been using phpmyadmin to manage databases for a few projects I am working on. I have very basic knowledge so sorry if this is a stupid question but today I have got this error, which I'm not sure how to solve.

"Your web browser does not support local storage of settings or the quota limit has been reached, some features may not work properly for you. In Safari, such problem is commonly caused by "Private Mode Browsing"."

I am unable to use phpmyadmin now as this pops up every time I try to access any tables or databases. 
Is anybody able to tell me how to fix this?

Comment: remove some unnecessary or previously used databases and tables that are not needed. take backups of those first and then delete

Comment: I think it may be your local browser web storage is full. Try a different browser.   If that works, clear the cache and assets on whatever browser had the issue

Comment: I have used another browser which has allowed me to remove any unnecessary databases. I have also cleared my cache in the browser it won't work in but still no luck...